# How to crop images after drawing the Region of Interest using drawfreehand?

Tags: matlab

I have an image and I want to crop it according to the ROI.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YcPM.jpg

I used the drawfreehand function to draw the Region of Interest(ROI). I want to crop the region under the ROI and save it in a different file.

```
I = imread('Intensity1.jpg');
imshow(I);
h = drawfreehand; % now pick ROI

BW = createMask(h); % get BW mask for that ROI
pos = images.roi.Freehand(); % get position for that ROI

% define bounding box
x1 =  round(min(pos(:,2)));
y1 =  round(min(pos(:,1)));
x2 =  round(max(pos(:,2)));
y2 =  round(max(pos(:,1)));

I2 = I.*uint8(BW); % apply mask to image
I2 = I2(x1:x2,y1:y2);

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(I);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(I2);
I3 = imcrop(I2);
imshow(I3)
```

The following error message is displayed.

Unrecognized method, property, or field 'roi' for class 'images.roi.Freehand'.

Error in fh4 (line 6)
pos = images.roi.Freehand(); % get position for that ROI

Comment: Using jpg to receive quantitative information from an image is not the best idea since jpg is not a looseless format.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that it is a good idea to replace loading of image files by some function available to everyone if asking questions like this*

The coordinates of the ROI are stored in the `Position` property of the object returned by `drawfreehand`:

```
imagesc(peaks(128))
h = drawfreehand;
pos = h.Position
```

**Update:** Here is a full example using your image:

```
I = imread('https://i.imgur.com/rsoCXsf.jpg');

f = figure();
imshow(I);
roi = drawfreehand();


mask = uint8(roi.createMask());
I2 = I .* mask; % apply mask
f2 = figure();
subplot(1,2,1);
image(I2);

% get BB
pos = roi.Position;
x1 =  round(min(pos(:,2)));
y1 =  round(min(pos(:,1)));
x2 =  round(max(pos(:,2)));
y2 =  round(max(pos(:,1)));

Icropped = I2(x1:x2, y1:y2, :);

subplot(1,2,2);
image(Icropped);
```

Comment: Hi Patrick,

I am getting the following error:

Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

Array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in fh4 (line 15)
I2 = I.*uint8(BW); % apply mask to image

Comment: I have updated my answer. It now contains a full example.